# print iframe content is not printing everything

Tags: javascript, html

I created a JavaScript function to print the content of my iFrame.

```
    <a href="#" onclick="printBGReport();" align="center">Print Report</a> <br/>
    <script>
        function printBGReport(){
            var content = document.getElementById("printBGReport").innerHTML;
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');
            mywindow.document.write(content);
            mywindow.document.close();
            mywindow.focus()
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
            //return;
        }
    </script>
<div id="printBGReport">
    <iframe id="reportBGID" name="reportBGID" src="myiFrameURL" width="900" height="1000" align="center" target="_self" valign="top" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no">
</div>
```

However, it is not printing all the content. Looks like it is just print the first page. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: How are the iframe contents structured exactly? What do you mean by "first page"?

Comment: The iframe content is structured in my <iframe> tag. It is a html content from another website. "first page" because it is a big content (multiples pages when print), but only the first page is printing.

Comment: It is just printing until the iframe height. height="1000"

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the iframe is pointing to a page on the same domain (see [CORS restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)), you can call `iframe.contentWindow.print()`.

```
document.getElementById("reportBGID").contentWindow.print()
```

If the iframe is pointing to another domain (which you have control of), you could use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to trigger a function on the page to call `window.print()`.

---

Alternatively, you could copy the iframe into a new window, and print that:

```js
function printIframe(iframe) {
  const tempWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800')

  const newIframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  newIframe.src = iframe.src

  newIframe.style = `border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;`
  tempWindow.document.body.style = `margin: 0;`

  tempWindow.document.body.appendChild(newIframe)

  newIframe.onload = () => {
    tempWindow.print()
    tempWindow.close()
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="printIframe(document.getElementById('iframe'));">
    Print Iframe
    </button>

<iframe id="iframe" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: It is not in the same domain and I don't have control of the domain

Comment: @CodeGuy Then it's impossible due to CORS restrictions

Comment: It is just printing until the iframe height. height="1000"

Comment: @CodeGuy Iframes don't have innerHTML, because they are shadow elements. The only way to get the iframe's content is to use `contentWindow`

Comment: That's why I used a div. Then, I put the iframe inside the div and I print the div.

Comment: @CodeGuy it doesn't work like that. You can't read anything inside an iframe without using contentWindow

Comment: I see. it is odd because when the print window displays, it shows all the iframe content, but when I click on print, it just prints until the iframe height size.

Comment: @CodeGuy Oh I see, you're copying the iframe. You should probably wait for it to load before calling print. Try wrapping it in a setTimeout

Comment: Actually the print button is displayed after the iframe is loaded. So, it should have been loaded when the user clicks on print. Right?

Comment: Same issue. It doesn't print all the content